# SelectMany after Select to get 2 int columns into single distinct List in EF Core 7

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have a table containing columns UserId1 and UserId2 and my goal is to load some rows based on different criterias into single distinct list. In other words I'm trying to get the List of user Ids.

```cs
await _dbContext.MyTable.Where(p => ...)
                .Select(p => new[] { p.UserId1, p.UserId2 })
                .SelectMany(id => id).Distinct().ToListAsync();
```

Executing the code throws an Exception

> 'The LINQ expression 'id => id' could not be translated. Either
> rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to
> client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable',
> 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

I know that I can load the sets into memory and execute SelectMany() on the loaded data but still, is there an efficient way to retrieve the distinct list of ints from 2 columns directly from the database into the single list?

Comment: My guess it has something to do with the projected select into a SelectMany. I'm assuming LiNQ to EF doesn't know how to translate that to a query. However, isn't your code functionally equivalent to `dbContext.MyTable.Where(p => ...).SelectMany(p => new[] { p.UserId1, p.UserId2 }).Distinct().ToListAsync();`? I think LINQ-to-EF can actually translate that.

Comment: @nbokmans thanks but not really equivalent as this query will produce a List of arrays and not a list of ints

Comment: did you actually try it? My IDE tells me this returns a list of ints as expected - that's what the `SelectMany(p => new[] { p.UserId1, p.UserId2 })` does.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read it carefully. Still, it produces the pretty much the same error
`The LINQ expression 'p => new int[]
{ 
    p.UserId1, 
    p.UserId2 
}' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.`

Comment: I'm getting the same error with `SelectMany(p => new[] ...`, but I'm running it against SQL Server rather than PostgreSQL. Using `Union` should work, but I don't know if that would be more efficient.

Comment: Are you using NPGSQL driver? It has a .NET equivalent to `array_arg` that might work. See the last item in the table here: https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/array.html

Comment: @JackA. from the description it looks like something I'm looking for but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly
`await _dbContext.MyTable.Where(p => ...)
                .Select(p => EF.Functions.ArrayAgg(new[] { p.UserId1, p.UserId2 })).ToListAsync()` but it's giving me an error
`'The 'ArrayAgg' method is not supported because the query has switched to client-evaluation. This usually happens when the arguments to the method cannot be translated to server. Rewrite the query to avoid client evaluation of arguments so that method can be translated to server.'`

Comment: I was assuming you'd call it like this: `EF.Functions.ArrayAgg(p.UserId1, p.UserId2)`. Unfortunately it's been a few years since I've worked with PostgreSQL and I don't currently have an instance to test with.

Comment: @JackA. unfortunatelly there is just one function accepting IEnumerable<T> without overloads

Answer (score 0):

You can't run such query via EF Core, but you can emulate:

```cs
var filtered = _dbContext.MyTable.Where(p => ...);

var result = await filtered
    .Select(p => p.UserId1)
    .Union(filtered.Select(p => p.UserId2))
    .ToListAsync();
```

`Distinct` is not needed, `Union` filters out duplicates.

Also compare performance with partial client-side calculation:

```cs
var result = (await filtered
    .Select(p => new[] { p.UserId1, p.UserId2 })
    .ToListAsync())
    .SelectMany(id => id)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any performance issues with that approach? If I understand it correctly this will produce a nested SQl-Query

Comment: You have no choice with EF Core. Or execute raw  CROSS APPLY SQL.